# Getting the annotations of a field directly

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

In a class, I have several fields that are anonymous classes.  Some of them have annotations.  For example:

```
public class MainClass {

    @Annotation
    public static Test t = new Test() {...}

    Interface Test {...}

}
```

I know I can view the annotation of t by doing MainClass.class.getField("t").getAnnotations(), but is there any way I can get the annotations for t by referencing t?  For example, if I have a collection of Tests, can I view their annotations by iterating through them?

```
Collection<Test> c;
...
// MainClass.t is in collection c
...

for (Test test : c) {

    // get annotation of test

}
```

I'm guessing this is not possible, and if not, is what's the best way to get close to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference simply points to an object and an object doesn't have any annotations. A field (method, class, parameter, etc.) does. So, no, it is not possible.

> what's the best way to get close to what I'm trying to do?

There is none.

```
public void someMethod() {
    Test test = MainClass.t;
    // some more
}
```

`MainClass.t` is a `Field`. The local variable `test` is just that, a local variable.

Note that you can annotate local variables

```
public void someMethod() {
    @SomeAnnotation
    Test test;
}

@Target(value = { ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE })
public @interface SomeAnnotation {

}
```

but there's no way to retrieve that annotation. It's mostly used by IDEs, for example `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Would there be any way for a field that's an anonymous class to see its own annotations?  Something like public static Test t = new Test() { ... this.getClass().doSomething }?

Comment: @user1940121 If your anonymous class has an instance field, you can access it the same way you normally do. With your example, `t.getClass().getField(...)`. That field would belong to the anonymous class (instance) only.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Test` is an interface and you want the annotations of the implementing classes.

```
for (Test test : c) {

    test.getClass().getField( "xx" ).getAnnotations()

}
```

Of cause you could use `test.getClass().getFiels()` to get all Fields and then get the annotations from them. Depends all on what you **really** want to do.